# Not able to integrate bluetooth module with ionic vue application

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, bluetooth

I am using ionic vue app, i need to integrate Bluetooth within application. I used "bluetooth-serial" node module but its not working, i shows an error like below image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaNWL.png)

Ionic : 5.4.16
Node : 12.18.3

I spent more time on this task but not able to achieve, please help me which package is need to install.
thank you

I need which package need to install

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.